# How to test the significance of covariance?

Tags: p-value, covariance, mutual-information

I'm using the [Mutual Informacion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) covariance in RNA sequences and I want to know if there exits a way to test if some covariance is significant, let's say, an associated p-value.

Thanks to all for your time.

Comment: Related question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48366/standard-errors-for-covariance-estimate-in-r