# The variance of variance-covariance matrix

Tags: variance, standard-error, covariance-matrix, order-statistics

Looking at [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/157305/102655) on the standard error of the variances and this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/48393/102655) on the standard error of the covariances, and knowing that both are part of the variance-covariance matrix, **$\Sigma$**, I am wondering if both formulas can be summarized in a single equation (probably in a matrix form).

The equation for the variance of the variance is

$\text{var}(s_{xx}^2) =  \frac{1}{n}\left(\mu_4 -\frac{n-3}{n-1} \sigma^4\right) $

where $\mu_4 = E(x-\mu_x)^4$ and $\sigma_x^4 = ((x-\mu_x)^2)^2)$

and the standard error of the covariance is

$\text{var}(s_{XY})=\frac{(n−1)^2}{n^3}(μ_{22}-μ_{11}^2)+ \frac{(n−1)}{n^3} ( μ_{20} μ_{02}-μ_{11}^2 )$

where $\mu_{rs}=E[(X-\mu_{_X})^r\,(Y-\mu_{_Y})^s]$.

Thank you,

---

EDIT:

I have found a good approximation as $(n^{-1}X^{2\prime}X^2)-(X^{\prime}Xn^{-1})^2$, where $X$ is centered, $X=X-\bar{X}$, and $^2$ is element-wise. In R:

```
round((t(X^2)%*%(X^2)*N^-1-((t(X)%*%X)*N^-1)^2),3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take this (I personally haven't checked it):

> $\text{var}(s_{XY})=\frac{(n−1)^2}{n^3}(μ_{22}-μ_{11}^2)+
>  \frac{(n−1)}{n^3} ( μ_{20} μ_{02}-μ_{11}^2 )$
>
> where $\mu_{rs}=E[(X-\mu_{_X})^r\,(Y-\mu_{_Y})^s]$.

Then
$\text{var}(s_{XX})=\frac{(n−1)^2}{n^3}(μ_{22}-μ_{11}^{2})+\frac{(n−1)}{n^3} ( μ_{20} μ_{02}-μ_{11}^2 )$
should still hold, since it is already generalized.

\begin{cases}
\mu_{11}=E[(X-\mu_{_X})\,(X-\mu_{_X})] = E[(X-\mu_{_X})^2]=s_{XX}=\sigma^2\\
\mu_{22}=E[(X-\mu_{_X})^2\,(X-\mu_{_X})^2]=\kappa s_{XX}=\mu_4\\
\mu_{20}=\mu_{02}=E[(X-\mu_{_X})^0\,(X-\mu_{_X})^2] = E[(X-\mu_{_X})^2] = s_{XX} = \sigma^2
\end{cases}

So

$$\text{var}(s_{XX})=\frac{(n−1)^2}{n^3}(\mu_4-(\sigma^2)^{2})+\color{red}{\frac{(n−1)}{n^3} ( (\sigma^2)(\sigma^2)-(\sigma^2)^2 )}\\
=\frac{(n−1)^2}{n^3}(\mu_4-\sigma^4)
$$

Discrepancies are due to Bessel's correction (probably).

---

In [their answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/48393/60613), glen_b says that

> Note that correcting this for the $\frac{1}{n-1}$ version is a simple matter of multiplying the above result by $(\frac{n}{n-1})^2$.

This would lead to:

$$\text{var}(s_{XX})=\frac{n^2}{(n−1)^2}\frac{(n−1)^2}{n^3}(\mu_4-\sigma^4)\\
=\frac{1}{n}(\mu_4-\sigma^4)
$$

So still not quite your first result.